# ejs file creating problem for me and my login system code

Tags: css, node.js, ejs

```
app.post('/users/update',async(req,res)=>{
    try{
        const user = await User.findOne({email:req.body.email});
        if(!user)
        {
            return res.send({message:"Email ID not registered!"})
        }
        // SG.K_2ita5rRLWvBO6ind1FzQ.uXUAMa1IzOHV155Sak74blUlmawGeUeRXQ20O5tF
        
        const otp=Math.floor(Math.random()*10).toString()+Math.floor(Math.random()*10).toString()+
        Math.floor(Math.random()*10).toString()+Math.floor(Math.random()*10).toString()
        const pass = await bcrypt.hash(otp,8)
        console.log(pass)
        var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
            service: 'gmail',
            auth: {
              user: 'vishalkrb@gmail.com',
              pass: 'k'
            }
          });

          var mailOptions = {
            from: 'vishalkrb@gmail.com',
            to: user.email,
            subject: 'Verification Email',
            text: `Hello, ${user.name}! Please verify with the following OTP`,
            html:'<h1>'+otp+'</h1>'
          };
          
          transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
            if (error) {
              console.log(error);
            } else {
              console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
              user.pass = pass
              **res.render('forgotPass2',{
                  user:user
                })**
            }
          });

    }catch(e){
        res.status(400).send(e)
    }
})

app.post('/users/update/:id',async(req,res)=>{
    try{
    
        const user = await User.findOne({_id:req.params.id})
        console.log(user)
         
    }catch(e){
        res.status(400).send(e)
    }
})
```

forgotPass2.ejs file is here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1" />
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
 
    <title>Sign Up</title>
    <style>
      body{background-color:red;}
    <script>
       
    
        function validate()
        {
            var otp=document.getElementById("otp");
            if(otp.value.trim()=="")
            {
                otp.style.borderColor="red";
                alert("Enter OTP!");
                return false;
            }
        }
        
        function offline()
        {
            alert("Oops! Make sure have an internet connection...")
            
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onoffline="offline()">
    <div id="box">
        <div id="leftbox">
            <h1>Forgot Password</h1>
            **<form onsubmit="return validate()" action="/users/update/<%= user.id %>" method="POST">**
                <input type="text" name="otp" placeholder="Enter OTP sent to your Email" id="otp" spellcheck="false" autofocus> 
                <input type="submit">
            </form>
            <a href="/">Create an Account?</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Problem1: an error comes when the above form is submitted. It tells that user is not defined. How on the earth is it possible, I am passing the user object in the first router! However surprisingly from the second router user is consoled out i.e it gets the user id successfully!

Problem2: this ejs file is not getting styled either with external css or internal one! It really irritates.

Pls help me with this as I am still in an early phase...

Comment: Can you  attach a screenshot of full error that's showing?

Answer (score 0):

## Suggestion

Make changes to the following code

```
// Change 1.
const user = await User.findOne({email:req.body.email}).lean(); // So it returns plain old javascript object


// Change 2.
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
            if (error) {
              console.log(error);
            } else {
              console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
              const updatedUser = {...user, pass: pass} // clone the user object into a new variable and add the new field (pass) 
              res.render('forgotPass2',{
                  user: updatedUser // Don't forget to update here too
                })
            }
          });


// Change 3.
// Update from this <%= user.id %> to this <%- user.id %> in your form action

<form onsubmit="return validate()" action="/users/update/<%- user.id %>" method="POST">
                <input type="text" name="otp" placeholder="Enter OTP sent to your Email" id="otp" spellcheck="false" autofocus> 
                <input type="submit">
            </form>
```

Comment: Not working yet! Neither is the css getting rendered nor I am sent to the router /users/update/:id but now sent to /users/update/

Comment: The issue could be when you load the route '/users/update' for the first time to render forgotPass2.ejs. I see it uses 'req.body.email', where is this coming from? Please share your error log if any.

Comment: The issue could be when you load the route '/users/update' for the first time to render forgotPass2.ejs. I see it uses 'req.body.email', where is this coming from? Please share your error log if any.

Comment: req.body.email is coming from <form> 's input type email, where i am asking email so that i could send an otp there... and there is no error log btw!